# Rounding Down number to the 60

Tags: sql-server

How can I round a number to interval of `60` ?
For instance if I have number `61`, It should round of to `60` and if number is `150`, it should round of to `120` and in case of `59` it should round off to `zero`.

Comment: the number might not be an integer, so it's probably safest to use FLOOR(YourVal / 60) * 60

Comment: @Cato or modulus %

Comment: also - watch out for negative values - if applicable - what should happen there can vary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To truncate values multiply by 60 and divide by 60. See demo:

```
SELECT 61/60*60 --result: 60
SELECT 59/60*60 --result: 0
```

Number must be int (bigint, smallint, tinyint). If it's not, use CAST/CONVERT.

See also [Division (Transact SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/divide-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> If an integer dividend is divided by an integer divisor, the result is
>   an integer that has any fractional part of the result truncated.

Answer (score 2):

ugly but it works:
Integer Division Then Multiply

```
SELECT (125 / 60 ) * 60
```

Answer (score 2):

Think this is what you're after

```
DECLARE @TestVal INT = 59
SELECT @TestVal - (@TestVal % 60)

SET @TestVal = 61
SELECT @TestVal - (@TestVal % 60)

SET @TestVal = 150
SELECT @TestVal - (@TestVal % 60)
```

Comment: Posted late sorry

Comment: I agree, `%` is the way to go with this, especially as OP didn't specify data types in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative is to use the [modulus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/modulo-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) operator to get the remainder of a division by 60 then subtract it:

> **% (Modulus) (Transact-SQL)**
>
> Returns the remainder of one number divided by another.

For example:

```
declare @valueToTest int = 150
select @valueToTest - (@valueToTest % 60) as result

-- result: 120
```

So this gets the remainder when you divide the `@valueToTest` by 60 and subtracts it from the original `@valueToTest`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer FLOOR over relying on Integer division, it's what FLOOR is for.  example

```
DECLARE @YourVal DECIMAL(10,4) = 220.1234;
SELECT @YourVal / 60 * 60, FLOOR(@YourVal / 60) * 60;
```